# Mapreduce job restarts twice and fails

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I am trying to submit a simple hive query with inner join. I could see in map reduce logs mapper increases to 80%, then restarts and again increases to 90%, then restarts to 0% and finally fails with below error:

> 8368527 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Please assist what could be the issue.

Comment: Carefully study logs on job tracker. They are more informative and you will find the reason.

Comment: The reason it restarts a few times is that map/reduce tasks will typically retry a specific task upon failure.  For some reason - 80-90% of the way through one of your map tasks, it is failing, then retrying, and failing again, etc.  If you go to the resource manager, click on the failed application, you should be able to find logs for the specific mappers that failed, and much more detailed logging.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got the logs as " Application application_1480447608640_51957 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1480447608640_51957_000002 exited with exitCode: -104
Diagnostics: Container[pid=899,containerID=container_e319_0001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.0 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container". Below is my cluster config.

Comment: Memory Used - 7.95 TB , Memory Total-11.30 TB,Memory Reserved-4 GB ,VCores Total 3910 , Minimum Allocation - <memory:1024, vCores:1> ,Maximum Allocation - <memory:12288, vCores:4>

Comment: Please advice which properties needs to be reset so that this job will not fail any more.